# assigning a layout for an entire controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

is there any way to assign an entire controller to use a certain layout? I know you can assign the layout in the ViewStart, is there anyway for the viewStart to know what controller is being used?

My objective is to have two admin layouts, one with an extra navbar when you are working with anything in the admin controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom action filter:

```
public class LayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _layout;
    public LayoutAttribute(string layout)
    {
        _layout = layout;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = _layout;
        }
    }
}
```

and then decorate your controller with it and all actions (returning view results obviously) withing this controller will use the layout you have specified:

```
[Layout("_SimpleLayout")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```